# Asp.net custom 404 not working using Intelligencia rewriter

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

Web.config :

```
<customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Page-Introuvable" />
  </customErrors>
```

Rewriter.config :

```
<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/Page-Introuvable" to="~/PageNotFound.aspx" />
</rewriter>
```

When typing this unexisting url :

> http://example.com/qwerty.aspx

I get to see my error 404 custom page

When typing this :

> http://example.com/qwerty (without .aspx)

I get server page 404 error

I'd like to know how to display my custom page in this case.

Thank you very much!

**ANSWER**

Added this to web.config section System.webServer :

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <clear/>
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="Redirect" path="PageNotFound.aspx"/>
  </httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<customErrors>` are just for extensions handled by asp.net (aspx, ashx...), for all others use `<httpErrors>`: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" defaultPath="/error.aspx?code=404">
        <clear/>
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error.aspx?code=404"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the only problem is that defaultPath is locked by default. I wrote a working answer in my question. That helped me alot!

Comment: @JoRouss: Your welcome, and by the way, its in your best interest to unlock (better hosting companies do it by default) and always specify a defaultPath, otherwise you are exposing your app's inner workings to potentially malicious users - its a security consideration.